# Navigating to same controller with different parameters with UI-Router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm performing an operating in a modal on a page within AngularJS. Once the operation is completed, I am calling the routing mechanism as follows:

```
$state.go('pagename', { id: someid});
```

Effectively I'm trying to navigate from `/pagename/1` to `/pagename/2`. However, when I call `$state.go`, it does not navigate to the new page, presumably because I am already technically on it. Is there a way to update/refresh the current view with the new `URL` parameters?

Comment: Could you try with $state.go('pagename', {id:id}, {reload: true});

Answer (score 0):

```
$state.go('pagename', { id: someid }, { reload: true });
```

If you look at this [github.io](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state) page, at the go(to, params, options) section there's a bit on the 'options'. In your case the params -have- changed, so that's why I suggest including the *reload: true* options.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.